# What is difference between UART and i2c

Tags: i2c, uart

Why do we need communication protocol and what is the difference between UART and i2c other than clock?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a lack of effort/research.

Comment: Stack exchange sites are for the questions which remain *after* doing basic research.  What have you learned in your reading and research on the subject so far?

Comment: i know we use communication protocol to transfer data,uart and i2c are ways of communication,apart from the basic differences like clock,master slave,i want to know how to calculate clock speed in i2c

Answer (score 9):

There are many differences, but to name a few:

- Transmission speed for I2C is selectable from a few predefined values, serial can be any speed, from very low to very high
- UART is typically for a point to point connection, I2C is a bus protocol
- UART is not a protocol (see also remark of Justme below), I2C is a protocol
- UART is (can be) full duplex, I2C is not
- UART does not have a master/slave principle (no protocol), I2C has
- UART can be used for transmission over distance, I2C is not meant for that.

So, there are a lot of differences. First find out what you need, than search the best protocol and hardware peripheral (UART, I2C, SPI, GPIO) for it.

Comment: how can we determine speed in i2c,i know in case of uart it is baud rate

Comment: @PRASH With an oscope? Or are you asking how you can configure a speed? I'd check with the datasheet of your master.

Comment: It can be configured depending on the master as KingDuken mentions. See also https://www.i2c-bus.org/speed/ :  The speed grades (standard mode: 100 kbit/s, full speed: 400 kbit/s, fast mode: 1 mbit/s, high speed: 3,2 Mbit/s) are maximum ratings. Compliant hardware guaranties that it can handle transmission speed up to the maximum clock rate specified by the mode.

Comment: Suppose i am using controller with 16Mhz which acts as master.how to set the standard mode speed of 100kbits/s in i2c

Comment: That depends on the registers to be used, or if you have an external I2C IC how to program it, and if you're lucky you have a library to set it up. Eg for an Arduino the call is `setClock` in the Wire library:  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireSetClock

Comment: If we don't have library,is there any formula for it,will timers register  be used for setting the speed?it would be helpful if you explain me with example ( like 8051) or just give links where i can read

Comment: @MichelKeijzers one correction, RS-232 is not a protocol. It is only a physical interface or physical layer, meant for synchronous or asynchronous data exchange. UART is the device that is *usually* used to perform the asynchronous start stop link layer over RS-232 physical interface, but RS-232 does not itself define character encoding, character framing, bit transfer order, bit rates etc (except for the maximum).

Comment: @Justme thanks for the addition (I adapted the answer).